# Zooming into Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Hi just a quick question, I have a 30" monitor, and when the IB section of Xcode is open the iPhone screen rectangle looks pretty small, and theres loads of wasted space around it. Is there a way of akin this bigger on the screen without actually making the dimensions bigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't look like it:

[image: Xcode Editor > Canvas > Zoom menu shows 100% as highest zoom level]

The interface builder storyboard canvas is limited to 100% as maximum zoom.

Comment: Hey I don't have that 'Zoom' menu under Editor>Canvas... I'm on the newest Xcode version BTW

Comment: The 'Zoom' menu only seems to be present on storyboards.

Comment: How to go past 100%?

Answer (score 2):

To zoom within Interface Builder, be sure to have the storyboard selected then use the following keyboard shortcuts.

**ZOOM IN**  -  <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>

**ZOOM OUT** - <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

**ZOOM TO 100%** - <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>

Comment: Is there one to jump back to 100%

Comment: @dumbledad Yes, please find it in my updated answer.

Comment: How to go past 100%?